# When using custom Gradle plugin :Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

Tags: gradle

I defined a custom gradle plugin and  its output is  MyPlugin.jar. i put the jar in build_libs dir. here is the way i use it:
 1) in Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
            flatDir {dirs 'build_libs'}
    }

    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
            classpath 'com.wonbin.myplugin:MyPlugin'
    }
}

allprojects {
        repositories {
                jcenter()
        }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2) in app module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.wonbin.myplugin.RunPlugin'
```

3) when i run  ./gradlew assemble

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not find com.wonbin.myplugin:MyPlugin:.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/wonbin/myplugin/MyPlugin//MyPlugin-.pom
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/wonbin/myplugin/MyPlugin//MyPlugin-.jar
>
>   ```
>    file:/home/wonbin/MyApp/build_libs/MyPlugin-.jar
>
>    file:/home/wonbin/MyApp/build_libs/MyPlugin.jar
>   ```
>
>   Required by:
>          project :

I don't not understand  'classpath' in denpendencies , so what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you don't need to set a group for dependency in your case, because if you use a `flatDir` repository, group is ignored and you can only set dependency name and it's version(it's optional). So you can try to declare your dependency as:

```
classpath 'MyPlugin'
```

Comment: what a silly mistake  i have made.

as described here:
> file:/home/wonbin/MyApp/build_libs/MyPlugin-.jar

>file:/home/wonbin/MyApp/build_libs/MyPlugin.jar
i shoud put the build_libs in root dir, but i put it in app module dir!!!